# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to boot after installing graphics drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics

I recently was trying to set up my Ubuntu laptop to play league of legends. I had downloaded wine, and I think I downloaded some incorrect graphics drivers. ( I believe this is the cause of my current problem). I can’t find the command I used to update the drivers, but I know it was an intel driver update.

The graphics driver update said to reboot to apply the updates, and since I rebooted for the first time, whenever I switch my laptop on it hangs during boot at this screen.

[image: boot hanging]

To play league I had downloaded Lutris, and it’s associated packages.

I can get to a root terminal by hitting escape while the laptop is booting. Any help would be highly appreciated!

EDIT: I can get the laptop to boot into the desktop by booting into recovery mode, and then booting normally from recovery mode. Doing this takes me to the login screen where I can login to my account.

It doesn’t pick up the secondary monitor when I do this, and there does seem to be other problems and it’s obviously not a long term fix.

I also found a list of all the commands I typed into terminal from the desktop before the crash, here they are.

```
592  sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
593  sudo apt install wine-stable
594  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lutris-team/lutris
595  sudo apt-get update
596  sudo apt-get install lutris
597  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
598  sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
599  sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
600  sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
601  sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
// These commands were used post problem to try fix the issue
602  xrandr
603  sudo apt-get install lightdm
604  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
605  sudo apt remove lutris
606  less /var/log/dpkg.log | grep install
607  sudo prime-select intel
608  sudo systemctl restart display-manager
609  history
```

Further attempts at a fix:

```
617  sudo apt-get remove .*:i386
618  dpkg --remove-architecture i386
619  sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

EXTRA-INFO: This is a grab of all the packages I installed before the crash and persistent boot problem started. (sorry) I know its a lot but there might be a clue as to what could be causing the problem.

```
2020-03-25 18:54:00 install fluid-soundfont-gm:all <none> 3.1-5.1
2020-03-25 18:54:00 status half-installed fluid-soundfont-gm:all 3.1-5.1
2020-03-25 18:54:12 install fluid-soundfont-gs:all <none> 3.1-5.1
2020-03-25 18:54:12 status half-installed fluid-soundfont-gs:all 3.1-5.1
2020-03-25 18:54:13 install python3-evdev:amd64 <none> 0.7.0+dfsg-2
2020-03-25 18:54:13 status half-installed python3-evdev:amd64 0.7.0+dfsg-2
2020-03-25 18:54:13 install p7zip:amd64 <none> 16.02+dfsg-6
2020-03-25 18:54:13 status half-installed p7zip:amd64 16.02+dfsg-6
2020-03-25 18:54:13 install mesa-utils:amd64 <none> 8.4.0-1
2020-03-25 18:54:13 status half-installed mesa-utils:amd64 8.4.0-1
2020-03-25 18:54:13 install lutris:amd64 <none> 0.5.4
2020-03-25 18:54:13 status half-installed lutris:amd64 0.5.4
2020-03-25 18:54:13 status installed fluid-soundfont-gs:all 3.1-5.1
2020-03-25 18:54:13 status installed fluid-soundfont-gm:all 3.1-5.1
2020-03-25 18:54:13 status installed p7zip:amd64 16.02+dfsg-6
2020-03-25 18:54:14 status installed python3-evdev:amd64 0.7.0+dfsg-2
2020-03-25 18:54:14 status installed mesa-utils:amd64 8.4.0-1
2020-03-25 18:54:14 status installed lutris:amd64 0.5.4
2020-03-25 18:54:15 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
2020-03-25 18:54:15 status installed hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2020-03-25 18:54:15 status installed mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
2020-03-25 18:54:15 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2
2020-03-25 18:54:17 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-03-25 19:00:18 install libzstd1:i386 <none> 1.3.3+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2020-03-25 19:00:18 status half-installed libzstd1:i386 1.3.3+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2020-03-25 19:00:18 status half-installed libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.2
2020-03-25 19:00:18 status half-installed libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.2
2020-03-25 19:00:18 status half-installed libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.2
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.2
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libosmesa6:i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libosmesa6:i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libglx-mesa0:i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libglx-mesa0:i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libglx-mesa0:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libglx-mesa0:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libglapi-mesa:i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:19 status half-installed libglapi-mesa:i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:20 status half-installed libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:21 status half-installed libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:21 status half-installed libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status half-installed libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:22 install libvulkan1:i386 <none> 1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status half-installed libvulkan1:i386 1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status half-installed libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status half-installed libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status half-installed libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status half-installed libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libvulkan1:i386 1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 2.4.100-4~kisak~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 2.4.100-4~kisak~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libzstd1:i386 1.3.3+dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libglapi-mesa:amd64 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libglapi-mesa:i386 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libosmesa6:i386 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libglx-mesa0:amd64 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libglx-mesa0:i386 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:00:22 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-03-25 19:01:00 install libwayland-client0:i386 <none> 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:01:00 status half-installed libwayland-client0:i386 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:01:00 install libxcb-randr0:i386 <none> 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04
2020-03-25 19:01:00 status half-installed libxcb-randr0:i386 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04
2020-03-25 19:01:00 install mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 <none> 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:01:00 status half-installed mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:01:01 install mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 <none> 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:01:01 status half-installed mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:01:01 status installed libxcb-randr0:i386 1.13-2~ubuntu18.04
2020-03-25 19:01:01 status installed mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:01:01 status installed libwayland-client0:i386 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.3
2020-03-25 19:01:01 status installed mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 20.0.2~kisak2~b
2020-03-25 19:01:01 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
```

Comment: I think the problem might come from the mesa ppa ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion. I've deleted it from the list of repositories. Will try a reboot (fingers crossed).

Comment: Update: removing the repository didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Whats your graphics card? If it is nvidia you may want to download a newer kernel version or use ubuntu 19.10 or wait for the next LTE realese. I think is launched next week

Comment: Even with sudo apt update ? Maybe it is the "sudo prime-select intel" command even if i don't think so because it disable nvidia drivers.

Comment: I think it is this, I'm almost certain my mac doesn't have a graphics card in it. But this is the line that came up in lspci: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller:Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller

Comment: Just removing the repository does not remove the packages you installed from it. It just "orphans" them leaving them without a source. You must remove/downgrade the packages that you installed from the repository. The program ppa-purge can help tremendously with this. I agree that the kisak ppa is likely the problem.

Comment: I tried to remove packages further, and ended up doing something probably quite foolish. sudo apt-get remove .*kisak2~b, which made me loose all desktop functionality. After that I went for the nuclear option and reinstalled from my live USB.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution to install `vulkan` without the booting problem. All you need is to install vulkan only by the following command:

`sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386`

Worked for me...